# What is Restful Routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, rest

I'm familiar with Ruby On Rails's routing system and well as how Code Igniter and PhpCake route things but is there more to it than having a centralized location where you give out routes based on a directory structure? Like this

```
controller/action/id/
Admin/editUser/22
```

Answer (score 21):

The basic premise is, instead of relying exclusively on the URL to indicate what webpage you want to go to (and just using the one method), it's a combination of VERB and URL.

This way, the same URL, when used with a different verb (such as GET, PUT, POST, DELETE), will get you to a different page. This makes for cleaner, shorter URLs, and is particularly adapted to CRUD applications, which most web apps are.

Answer (score 14):

RESTful Rails routes, i think that this shows the principle of REST

```
/users/       method="GET"     # :controller => 'users', :action => 'index'
/users/1      method="GET"     # :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
/users/new    method="GET"     # :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
/users/       method="POST"    # :controller => 'users', :action => 'create'
/users/1/edit method="GET"     # :controller => 'users', :action => 'edit'
/users/1      method="PUT"     # :controller => 'users', :action => 'update'
/users/1      method="DELETE"  # :controller => 'users', :action => 'destroy'
```

Comment: except, of course, that `/users/new` and `/users/1/edit` are not REST URIs (on account of having a verb in them). That said, you could have 'functional pages' as a resource that you can 'GET' ie `/users/tools/creation_form` and `/users/tools/edit_form/1` (note in the second URI I have added a user ID to populate the form for you)

Answer (score 2):

One big part of the whole restful thing is that you should use the different HTTP methods to represent different actions.

For example in Rails if you were to send a `HTTP Delete` to `/users/[id]` it would signify that you want to delete that user. `HTTP Get` would retrieve an appropriate representation of the user. `HTTP Put` can update or create a user.

These are some examples, but since there is no standard for RESTful API's in HTTP this is not correct in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

it maps HTTP VERBS + URL to a specific action in the controller

Example:

```
GET /users/1
```

goes to  :

```
:controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

to see the full mapping, go to the terminal, and type:

```
rake routes
```

Answer (score 0):

@edtsech is correct. I would like to add one more thing here.

In the case of update,the method is "POST" with a hidden field which contains the data need to be updated.

So PUT =  POST + Hidden field.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say here... POST is most certainly not meant to be used for updating records... and by 'hidden field' do you mean the payload?

Comment: In Rails, to update the record we use the POST request with hidden field which contains the payload.