# Rails, restful versus non-restful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful-url

Something like `resources :products` will create 7 different restful routes for CRUD operations for resource `products.` For example: `products GET    /products(.:format)            products#index`

So restful route includes only controller name within itself and `:id` for operation like `edit, show, update, delete.`**So as i get this, first requirement(in rails) for route(to be precisely URL) to be restful is that route can't contain action name?** Q1

Second requirement for route to be restful is that action corresponding to route must "play by restful rules" in another word, for example a `GET` should not leave side-effects on the server, but just retrieve data. So if i have `/products(.:format)            products#index` and within index action i saved something into DB, than above route is just looks like restful route but in fact it isn't?

When i create non-restful routes in rails for example: `get ':controller/:action/:id'` i only can see difference that i **must** explicitly write `:action`, so that `":action`" makes this route non-restful?

To me seems that restful in rails is everything about CRUD? An second i don't need non-restful routes at all, when i can make a bunch of restful routes with construct like following(and other similar construct)?

```
resources :products do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

From this point and i'm relatively new to all of this, reading a lot about REST concept, and if im right about my first question(Q1) is that only difference between restful and non-restful route in rails?

Comment: The restful concept is explained pretty well in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441962/what-is-restful-routing