# Rails routes: namespace + resource + collection vs match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

How does using a namespace + resource + collection compare to using a match.

For example, say I want to handle all HTTP methods for some endpoint.

```
namespace :webhooks do
  resources :some_service, only: :none do
    collection do
      get    :some_action
      post   :some_action
      put    :some_action
      patch  :some_action
      delete :some_action
    end
  end
end

# Compare to

match '/webhooks/some_service/some_action', to: 'webhooks/some_service#some_action', via: :all
```

Here are the associated routes according to `rake routes`:

```
                                 Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action

some_action_webhooks_some_service_index GET      /webhooks/some_service/some_action(.:format)      webhooks/some_service#some_action
                                        POST     /webhooks/some_service/some_action(.:format)      webhooks/some_service#some_action
                                        PUT      /webhooks/some_service/some_action(.:format)      webhooks/some_service#some_action
                                        PATCH    /webhooks/some_service/some_action(.:format)      webhooks/some_service#some_action
                                        DELETE   /webhooks/some_service/some_action(.:format)      webhooks/some_service#some_action
      webhooks_some_service_some_action          /webhooks/some_service/some_action(.:format)      webhooks/some_service#some_action
```

Besides line count, are there reasons why I should prefer one way over the other?

Answer (score 1):

In this case `match` is the best solution. The resources config should be used primary for defining restful routes (plus some exceptional other routes), which as the keyword already says implies of having some Resource as an endpoint.
E.g you use `Session#create` instead of `AuhtService.perfom_sing_in` (having Session as the restful Resource instead of performing an rpc call to a service)

In your case you're not having any REST semantics in the routes at all, so match is just fine

Comment: The [answers for this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441962/what-is-restful-routing) suggest that restful routing is the combination of HTTP methods + URL to achieve different outcomes. If that's the case, I think both examples above are restful. But let's say there is a resource at the endpoint, e.g. `match '/api/library/book', to: 'api/library#book', via: :all` which allows you to do stuff like creating a book, updating a book, and deleting a book (if you use the appropriate HTTP method, otherwise you get a 405 response). Is the `resources` method better to use now?

Comment: In that case i can see nothing wrong in both ways. It's somewhat cumbersome to use ressources dsl for non-restfull routes, because match is exactly made for that, however `match` is a simple building block and it's nothing wrong to use it for restfull routes if you can define them more elegantly. But somebody may also argue that using the ressource dsl in that case is more explicit and therefore is a self documented code indicating that you have a resfull ressouce

Comment: Good point. I think the resources DSL is definitely more explicit and makes your intentions clear, compared to the match one-liner. And if you don't support certain HTTP methods, then you can say so with an inline comment next to that verb (e.g. # 405) when you use the resources DSL.